# Parsing JSON and Pulling Information To VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json, parser

I am having difficulty understanding how to take a parsed JSON list and saving it into an APEX list. My end goal is to have the Username and associated PriorityNumber listed out on a VF page.

I have read the related questions here and I just can't seem to understand the why behind what I am doing. If you look to the bottom of my class, when I try to loop through myParsedResult, I get an error saying that "Variable does not exist: JSON2Apex".

I have tried deserialization, the wrapper classes, directly putting javascript into my VFP, and many variations of the [Salesforce JSON page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm). If anyone could help exaplining how to save a parsed string into a list, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class WSController {
    public List<String> un {get;set;}
    public List<String> pn {get;set;}   
    public List<String> dmutc {get;set;}   

    String jsonStr = '{"DateModifiedUtc":"2016-09-07T20:12:47.1519119Z",' + 
'"AgentInfoList":[{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0}, ' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2}]}';


// Parse entire JSON response.    
    public List <String> WSController() { 
        //Returns the token that the parser currently points to
        parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);
        if (parser.nextToken() != null) 
        {
            while ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'Username'))
            {
                fieldName = parser.getText();
                //returns the value of the next token
                parser.nextToken();
                un.add(parser.getText());
                system.debug('this is the Username list: ' + un);
            }
            while ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'PriorityNumber'))
            {
                fieldName = parser.getText();
                //returns the value of the next token
                parser.nextToken();
                pn.add(parser.getText());
                system.debug('this is the Priority Number list: ' + pn);
            }
            while ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'DateModifiedUtc'))
            {
                fieldName = parser.getText();
                //returns the value of the next token
                parser.nextToken();
                dmutc.add(parser.getText());
                system.debug('this is the Date Modified: ' + dmutc);
            }
        }
        return pn;       
    }

    //wrapper class
    public class JSON2Apex 
    {
        public String DateModifiedUtc;
        public List<AgentInfoList> AgentInfoList;
    }
    public class AgentInfoList 
   {
        public String Username;
        public Integer PriorityNumber;
    }
    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) 
    {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }

    JSON2Apex myParsedResult = JSON2Apex.parse(jsonStr);

    public void myMethod(){
        for (AgentInfoList agentItem : myParsedResult){
            un = agentItem.Username;
            pn = agentItem.PriorityNumber;
        }
    }

}
```

In addition, as you can see, I am saving the username and priority number lists in the WSController and then again in the wrapper class. I was following [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm) but I feel like I should be able to write this without the wrapper class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"myMethod" didn't work because of compilation errors. Here's what it really should look like:

```
  for (AgentInfoList agentItem : myParsedResult.AgentInfoList){
        un.add(agentItem.Username);
        pn.add(agentItem.PriorityNumber);
  }
```

But that's overkill; AgentInfoList already has the data you need, so if you'd simply started off with that as a public variable, like this:

```
public class WSController {
    public JSON2Apex info { get; set; }

    String jsonStr = '{"DateModifiedUtc":"2016-09-07T20:12:47.1519119Z",' + 
'"AgentInfoList":[{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0}, ' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":0},{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":1},{"Username":"Agent00@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent01@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent02@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent03@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent04@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent05@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent06@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent07@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent08@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent09@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},{"Username":"Agent10@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2},' +
'{"Username":"Agent11@gmail.com","PriorityNumber":2}]}';

    //wrapper class
    public class JSON2Apex 
    {
        public String DateModifiedUtc { get; set; }
        public List<AgentInfoList> AgentInfoList { get; set; }
    }
    public class AgentInfoList 
   {
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public Integer PriorityNumber { get; set; }
    }
    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) 
    {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
    public WSController() {
        info = (JSON2Apex)parse(jsonStr);
    }
}
```

You can then use that data in a page like this:

```
Date Modified: {!info.DateModifiedUtc}
<br />
<apex:repeat value="{!info.AgentInfoList}" var="AgentInfo">
    {!AgentInfo.Username} has priority {!AgentInfo.priorityNumber}.<br />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank makes sense. I thought it was a bit over kill to be putting it in a list twice. So I am just saving the parsed string into 'info' and calling info on the VFP. But when I do this I am getting the error message--> 
"Unknown property 'WSController.JSON2Apex.DateModifiedUtc' " and if I take that out, I get error--> "Unknown property 'WSController.JSON2Apex.AgentInfoList'".  It seems like it does not understand JSON2Apex.

Comment: @Olivia classic mistake (I did it, too). You need to have public getters and setters; I've updated my code to show you what that would look like.

Comment: hum...it doesn't like the getter and setter. I tried putting is outside of the JSON2Apex class too but no avail. error message --> "unexpected token: '}'"

Comment: @Olivia It was missing a semi-colon. That was just a typo. I'll update. I just tested this in my sandbox to validate.

Comment: thank you! I got it up and running. I appreciate all of your help :)